# Remove "Troubleshoot Compatibility" with assembly info?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7

I am most certain this is something to do with my assembly, but when I compile my application Windows does not recognise that it is compatible with Windows 7 so puts the "Troubleshoot Compatibility" item in the context menu when right-clicking on the icon.

My assembly currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="process_libraries"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

What do I need to add to it to make Windows recognise that my application is compatible with Windows 7?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing obvious, not a manifest nor the exe header's Windows version nor the file location.  Taking the low road: how do you know it will be compatible with the next service pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with Assembly Info, you need to add a manifest to your EXE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711(VS.85).aspx explains everything. You can add a manifest in VS2010 easily from the project properties.

Comment: Yes. Or else I wouldn't have posted it.